# Sending AngularJS http GET authentication?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, authorization

I have captured some information from an app http session and am trying to decipher how the app is passing authentication.  I have tried multiple methods/combos but can't seem to figure out how they are passing credentials.

### The capture:

```
GET /features HTTP/1.1
user: thisUser@email.com
X-Password: ThisUserPassword
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1 max-stale=1
X-NewRelic-ID: VQ4AV1BbGwIIXVFXAwM=
Host: www.blah.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/2.3.0
If-None-Match: "d751713988987e9331980363e24189ce"

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Status: 304 Not Modified
ETag: "d751713988987e9331980363e24189ce"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Runtime: 0.034169
X-NewRelic-App-Data: PxQGWVFVDgsTVVdWBAYBVkYdFHANCBcQXw5UB0oXR1dBE1ACVBIcFgVOXj4LAl9aUzsUEVJDGAABUEJGEAMQQBxSFlIUCBoCAFAMUwRRC1FRAgZZUVMJARxJUE4VBgBVV1QGUFEHAAdSVAFXCBpp
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2017 13:55:45 GMT
X-Varnish: 405330697
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
X-Varnish-Cache: MISS
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

I have tried these combos:

```
var headers = {Authorization:"Basic thisUser@email.com:ThisUserPassowrd"} ;
var headers = {Authorization:"thisUser@email.com:ThisUserPassowrd"} ;
var headers = {Authorization:"Basic user:thisUser@email.com,X-Password:ThisUserPassowrd"} ;
var headers = {Authorization:"user:thisUser@email.com,X-Password:ThisUserPassowrd"} ;
```

I even tried encoding:

```
  var userCreds = btoa("thisUser@email.com:ThisUserPassowrd") ;
  //
  var headers = {"Authorization": "Basic" + userCreds} ;
  var headers = {"Authorization": userCreds} ;
```

Here is my http call, I am swapping in/out "Basic " & userCreds/userCreds1 for various tests:

```
  var userCreds = "thisUser@email.com:ThisUserPassword" ;
  var userCreds1 = btoa(userCreds) ;
  var baseUrl = "https://www.blah.com" ;
  var headers = {"Content-Type":"application/JSON", Authorization: userCreds1} ;
    var req = {  
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseUrl + '/features' ,
      headers: headers
    }
    return $http(req).then(function(response) {
```

The error I am getting is "UnauthorizedAccess: either email or password is incorrect".  I mean, is it looking for the actual fields "user" and "X-Password" to be passed in too?

Can someone help me figure what the correct method is here?

Answer (score 0):

My Assumption is they are passing user credentials inside a Ajax Call body via  a post call (or get).

username/password.

if it is a stateless app they will return some sort of token that you have to put inside the Authorization header.

the information you posted is not sufficient to help you out :(

Comment: please post the post/get for the login and the response.

Comment: Those are not the real user:password's listed, just an example of where they go.  The above capture is exactly how the app is placing the call.  I have added the captured HTTP response.  I know its an authorization format issue - just can't figure out where I am off.

Comment: What is am saying is that what you are showing me is that the return of a possible login call, that passes the username and password. Then some code where you are trying to pass the Authorisation header into some other call. what would help if you are showing a call that actually uses the Authorisation header.

Comment: I don't see anywhere Authorization header inside the Captured HTTP .. and is posted is some code that is trying to use it.. so it's hard to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Sorry...I added in my HTTP calls now.

Comment: I added "my" attempt to make the same HTTP call.  However, I don't have access to the code that I am trying replicate - thus I don't have the original app http call.

Comment: Please realize that nowhere in the posted header is there Authorization, there are two fields called user/X-Password

Comment: do you suppose "authorization" isn't used, and it simply should be: 'var headers = {"user":"thisUser,"X-Password":"thisPassword"}' - I am going to give that a shot.

Comment: Brantu - THANKS.  Your pointing out the lack of "authorization" in the HTTP response pointed me to the right place.  This api I am interfacing with literally uses what my most recent var headers suggestion was.  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here

```
 var userCreds = btoa("thisUser@email.com:ThisUserPassowrd") ;
 var headers = {"Authorization": "Basic" + userCreds} ;
 var headers = {"Authorization": userCreds} ;
```

You should add window before btoa and add a space after 'Basic'

```
 var userCreds = window.btoa("thisUser@email.com:ThisUserPassowrd") ;
 var headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + userCreds} ; //Note the space 
 var headers = {"Authorization": userCreds} ;
```